# Next.js router.back() changes the locale back to the old one

Tags: next.js

Whenever I go into profile settings and change the locale into anything (e.g. from /ar to /en) and then I click the button that takes me back to the previous page, it switches from /en back to /ar and the locale changes back to 'ar'.
I don't really know which of it is wrong. Is it my implementaion of localization? or is it how next/router works?

I tried plenty of ways to replace the paths as I go back but it was all for nothing as there were plenty of edge cases